# Emberjs-1.0 passing controller instance to ember components

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have created a **[DatePickerComponent](http://jsfiddle.net/FUdgY/)** and I am passing in two controller instances like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="appointment">
  {{date-picker datePickerController=datePickerController  timeSlotController=timeSlotController}}
```

From the inside the **[component](http://jsfiddle.net/FUdgY/)** I can fetch the **datePickerController** but when I try to fetch the **timeSlotController**, it always returns undefined. They are both defined thesame and passed in thesame way, so why is one undefined and the other is available. Both controllers and the components and router are pasted here.

```
App.DatePickerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  datePickerController: null,
  timeSlotController: null,

  didInsertElement: function() {
   this._super();
   _this = this;
   var datePicker, timeSlot;
   timeslot = _this.get('timeSlotController');
   datePicker = _this.get('datePickerController');

   alert(timeSlot);
   alert(datePicker);
  }
});
```

I added the **[DatePickerComponent](http://jsfiddle.net/FUdgY/)** to the **appointment template** below.

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="appointment">
   {{date-picker datePickerController=datePickerController  timeSlotController=timeSlotController}}

  <p class="first">   from appointment template</p> 
   {{datePickerController}}
   <br/>
  <p class="second"> from appointment template</p>
   {{timeSlotController}}
 <br/>
</script>
```

The strange thing is that when the appointment template renders based on the content above, it shows that the **timeSlotController** instance was passed on so it see:

```
 <App.TimeSlotController:ember319>
```

and

```
<App.DatePickerController:ember313>
```

But I added 2 alert to the component **alert(timeSlot)** and  **alert(datePicker)**

```
   alert(timeSlot);   gives undefined
  alert(datePicker);  returns **<App.DatePickerController:ember313> **
```

So ** alert(datePicker)**  returns thesame instance that was displayed in the template.

The appointment controller

```
App.AppointmentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['datePicker', 'timeSlot'],
  datePickerController:   Ember.computed.alias('controllers.datePicker'),
  timeSlotController: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.timeSlot')

});
```

The timeslot controller

```
 App.TimeSlotController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   content: [ ],
   //content: Ember.computed.alias('day'),
   contentBinding: 'day',
   day: ''   
 });
```

The date picker controller

```
 App.DatePickerController =  Ember.ArrayController.extend({ 
   needs: ['appointments', 'appointment'],
   //apptId: '', 
  appointments: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.appointments.content'),
  apptId:  Ember.computed.alias('controllers.appointment.content')
 });
```

The router

```
  App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('appointments', {path: "/"}, function(){ 
      this.resource('appointment', {path: "/:appointment_id"}, function(){
         this.resource('timeSlot', {path: '/:day'});                     
      });     
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: You have a typo in the code of the components didInsertElement should be timeSlot = _this.get('timeSlotController'); with the S capitalized http://jsfiddle.net/FUdgY/1/

Comment: Thanks @Edu. I checked through for all kinds of spelling mistakes or missing comma's and found nothing. Do you want to add it as an answer for me to accept. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the code of the components *didInsertElement* should be `timeSlot = _this.get('timeSlotController');` with the S capitalized

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  this._super();
  _this = this;
  var datePicker, timeSlot;
  //timeslot = _this.get('timeSlotController');
  timeSlot = _this.get('timeSlotController');
  datePicker = _this.get('datePickerController');

  alert(timeSlot);
  alert(datePicker);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FUdgY/1/